# Using Robocopy /minage: What is the Maximum number of days?

Tags: windows, robocopy

I'm trying to run a batch script using Robocopy but when I try to put in MinAge days of 10 years ago (for example 3653 days) it doesn't like it and I'm getting an 'Invalid switch' error.  If I put in the date 20110101 it works perfectly.  Just trying to figure out the maximum number of days I can use for the MinAge parameter.

I've looked on Microsoft support, here an elsewhere and I don't see this being addressed.  Thank you in advance for your time and answers.

Answer (score 0):

1899 is the maximum days you can put in for MinAge.